# How can I create a .proto from a .cs file (not the other way around)?

Tags: c#, python, protocol-buffers

## Situation

- I have some network traffic that is using Protobuf.
- I have the C# files and classes that specify information about the expected fields.
- I want to decode the packets.

## Problem

- Everything I find online seems to only explain how to generate .cs classes from a pre-built .proto file, and not the other way around (protobuf-net, protobuf-csharp-port).

Here is some example code of one of the files that I know has the information I need. There are several files similar to this:

```
namespace ExampleUtil
{
    using Google.ProtocolBuffers;
    
    [DebuggerNonUserCode, CompilerGenerated, GeneratedCode("ProtoGen", "2.4.1.473")]
    public sealed class UtilAuth : GeneratedMessageLite<UtilAuth, UtilAuth.Builder>
    {
        private static readonly string[] _utilAuthFieldNames = new string[] { "result" };
        private static readonly uint[] _utilAuthFieldTags = new uint[] { 8 };
        private static readonly UtilAuth defaultInstance = new UtilAuth().MakeReadOnly();
        private bool hasResult;
        
        static UtilAuth()
        {
            object.ReferenceEquals(Examplelite.Descriptor, null);
        }

        ...

        [CompilerGenerated, GeneratedCode("ProtoGen", "2.4.1.473"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public static class Types
        {
            [CompilerGenerated, GeneratedCode("ProtoGen", "2.4.1.473")]
            public enum PacketID
            {
                ID = 0xcc
            }

            [GeneratedCode("ProtoGen", "2.4.1.473"), CompilerGenerated]
            public enum Result
            {
                UNKNOWN,
                ALLOWED,
                INVALID,
                NO_SERVER
            }
        }
```

And so on. It seems like this was generated from a proto file, but I don't know how to get that back.

## The Goal

I'd ideally like to be able to open a stream up in Python, and using the generated proto file, simply print the contents in human-readable format.

Comment: Ho hmmm... if it was protobuf-net, you could just use `Serializer.GetProto<T>()`, but that looks like protobuf-csharp-port